# Remove/check iOS passcode programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm working on the development of a "check-in" type app for my iPad repair company. I'd like to enforce that a pass code is removed so I have full access to diagnose the device. This could be either removing a passcode programmatically or just providing instructions on how to remove a passcode and refusing to allow the repair request to be submitted without ensuring it was removed by the user. Preferably, I'd like to be able to do this in Swift but Obj-C is fine.

I would be working directly with schools and businesses as my main customers so I would be using an enterprise development account. No worries about App Store reviewers getting their messy hands on my API calls.

Currently all of my prospective customers are using an MDM with deployment functionality so that part should be a breeze.

Comment: Now that you have posted your requirements, what is your question? What research have you done?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to remove passcode from a iOS device.  But you can use one of the [Mobile Device Management](http://www.apple.com/support/business-education/mdm/) tool to remote wipe the device to reset the passcode.